# Vectorspace equality $F$ field, $V$ F-space, $A,B\subset V$, then $\langle A\rangle _F+ \langle B\rangle _F=\langle A \cup B\rangle _F$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Now I have an understanding problem I think.

$F$ is a field, $V$ is a vectorspace over $F$.

Theorem 3.2.4 of us states that if $A\subset V$, then $\langle A\rangle_F$ is the smallest subspace that contains A.

Theorem 3.2.5 of us states that $U+U'=\langle U\cup U'\rangle _F$, where $U,U'$ are subspaces of $V$.

My try so far:

Both $\langle A\rangle _F$ and $\langle B\rangle _F$ are subspaces of $V$, by theorem 3.2.4.

Therefore, by theorem 3.2.5 we use $U+U'=\langle U\cup U'\rangle _F$.

Therefore we have $\langle A\rangle _K+ \langle B\rangle _K=\langle \langle A\rangle _F\cup \langle B\rangle _F \rangle _F$.

I don't see how we can conclude $\langle \langle A\rangle _F\cup \langle B\rangle _F \rangle _F=\langle A\cup B\rangle _F$

In addition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $z\in\langle A\cup B\rangle_F.$ Then $z=k_1x_1+\cdots+k_nx_n$ for some scalars $k_i$ and some $x_1,\ldots,x_n\in A\cup B.$ Now assume WLOG that $x_1,\ldots,x_m\in A$ and $x_{m+1},\ldots,x_n\in B.$ Then $k_1x_1+\cdots+k_mx_m\in\langle A\rangle_F$ and $k_{m+1}x_{m+1}+\cdots+k_nx_n\in\langle B\rangle_F$ so $z\in\langle A\rangle_F+\langle B\rangle_F.$ Conversely, supposse that $z\in\langle A\rangle_F+\langle B\rangle_F.$ Then $z=x+y$ for some $x\in\langle A\rangle_F$ and $y\in\langle B\rangle_F.$ Now just use the same argument I used above (the fact that the linear span of a set $A$ is equal to the set of all linear combinations of the elements of $A$).